# Synchronization of remote files download

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Preamble: it's a self-assigned and pure syntetic task to learn (and remember what I already knew) C# threads and synchronization and data structures.

The original question was here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458937/synchronization-of-remote-files-download

The short task explanation:

Let's say I have a dictionary `<string, string>` that represents a path (http) to a file by some key, ie:

```
foo => http://domain.tld/file1
bar => http://domain2.tld/file2
```

And I'd like to implement a class that will implement an interface with 2 methods:

```
String Rand();
String Get(String key);
```

The first method would pick the file randomly from all the available, and the `Get` would return a particular file, or to be precise - local path to a downloaded file.

The class should be thread-safe, so that if several threads request the same `key` with `Get()` or the `Rand()` picks the same item - then **only one thread** should actually download a file to a local drive, or the path should be retrieved immediately if a file has already been downloaded.

My proof of concept solution is:

```
class Downloader
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, string> _map;
    private IDictionary<string, string> _storage = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<string>> _progress = new ConcurrentDictionary<string,Task<string>>();

    public Downloader(IDictionary<string, string> map)
    {
        _map = map ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public string Get(string key)
    {
        if (_storage.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return _storage[key];
        }

        Task<string> task;
        if (_progress.TryGetValue(key, out task))
        {
            return task.Result;
        }

        task = _retrieveFile(key);

        if (!_progress.TryAdd(key, task))
        {
            return Get(key);
        }

        task.Start();
        _storage[key] = task.Result;
        return task.Result;
    }

    private Task<string> _retrieveFile(string key)
    {
        string path;

        if (!_map.TryGetValue(key, out path))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The specified key wasn't found");
        }

        return new Task<string>(k =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Started retrieving {0}", k.ToString());
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("Finished retrieving {0}", k.ToString());
            return k.ToString() + " local path";
        }, path);
    }
}
```

The copy is at http://pastebin.com/LJnK7FB6

How could I make it better? Any particular problems with the code?

In the comments @I4V pointed out to some problems at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458937/synchronization-of-remote-files-download#comment23617420_16460673 but seems like I'm missing the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `_retrieveFile` to return a `Task` that's already started, you could simplify the whole `Get()` into just:

```
return _progress.GetOrAdd(key, _retrieveFile).Result;
```

Also, it seems that `Downloader` with empty `map` doesn't make sense, so you should check for that in your constructor, instead of using `??`.

Comment: That's a nice point actually, but shouldn't it be `_retrieveFile()`?

Comment: @zerkms No, there is an overload that accepts `Func`. Though I assumed that it's guaranteed that the delegate won't be executed more than once, which, according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677.aspx) is not true. So my code might not be good enough for you.